# what does it do dummy filler sql loader?

Tags: xml, oracle, sql-loader

hello I not understand dummy filler what it do?

someone explains it to me?

```
load data
  infile * "str '</contact>'" 
INSERT



 into table address_book
TRUNCATE
  FIELDS(
         dummy1 filler char(2000) terminated by "<contact>",
         contact_name char(2000) enclosed by "<contact_name>" and "</contact_name>",
         address char(2000) enclosed by "<address>" and "</address>",
         dummy2 filler char(2000) terminated by "</start>"
        )
BEGINDATA
```

example:dummy1 filler : It means to ignore everything until contact?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically at a high-level `Sqlldr` first matches a field as defined in the control file with a field in the data file.  Then if it also matches a column name it attempts to insert it into a table.

Note that the `str` part of the infile line:

```
infile * "str '</contact>'"
```

tells sqlldr that a record ends with the string `"</contact>"`.

So we can discern that `sqlldr` is to load some data from a contact record. In this case the data from the record will be read up until the string `"<contact>"` is found, and since it does not match a column name, and further it is defined as FILLER it will be ignored by sqlldr. It is only interested in the contact_name and address fields.

So to answer your question, yes.  :-)

Comment: Gary_W Thank you. your answer is very comprehensive